# Wrote the wrong university in cover letter for Phd Application

Tags: phd, application-cover-letter

I wrote the wrong university in my cover letter for applying for a Phd position, Should I send the corrected one to the Phd Program Coordinator or leave it as it is? Will this make them to throw off my application (my chance is zero)?

Comment: I got my (now completed) PhD position using a cover leter with the same mistake. So the chance is not 0, but I don't know how good/bad it is.

Comment: @wimi Thank you for ur comment, it made me feel better, I hope they will just laugh at my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can predict how another would react, but I'd guess the most common reaction would be a laugh and then just assume it was a mistake.

People expect that you would apply to more than one university. People make oversight errors and know that others do.

You could send a note, apologizing for the mistake and expressing your continuing interest in their program.

Comment: Someone is telling me to leave it as it is, If they have already read it then damage is done. If I tell them there is a mistake they will read it for sure. Maybe this mistake will grab attention to my application since the wrong university is a reputable one in my field.

Comment: I doubt that it would matter much either way. But every individual is different.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I would like to share something with u. After reading your answer, I got a brilliant Idea which is to send them an apology and take this chance to introduce myself and why im interested in their program and how i can contribute to it, and guess the happy surprise I did that and they replied to not worry about this issue and they are happy that I have applied for this job good luck!